# Execute stored procedure created by a different user over dblink

Tags: dblink

I have created a stored procedure **PROCA** in Database **A** with user **USERA** and given
execute permission to **USERB** and I could execute this stored proc in Database A when logged in with USERB.

Now I logged in to Database **X** and created a dblink **Akink** and this dblink conntects to
Database A with user USERB. Now when I execute stored proc using below syntax ,
it got executed without any error but whatever DML operations stored proc have done,
are not committed.

**Code to invoke stored proc from Databse X**

```
declare

begin

   USERA.PROCA@Alink();

   COMMIT;

end;
```

Please suggest what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no good solutions for such situations.
But here is a suggestion for you; try using this:

```
Exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@db_link('some ddl sql statment');
```

For example:

```
Exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@db_link('truncate table test_tab');
```